# Get all entries where the following entry is not +1 minute

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, timestamp

I have a table which stores all my executed jobs. Know I want to know if all the jobs get executed properly (every minute). Each entry has a `created_at` timestamp.

My question now is how can I select all entries which where not executed 1 minute after the last entry. This is a very complex query I feel like. So far I just have all the entries orderd by `created_at`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
WHERE created_at IS NOT NULL 
ORDER By created_at
```

`created_at` is a timestamp. Something like `2020-02-02 10:00:00`.

Table Structure:

```
id    job_name  created_at
-----------------------------------
1     ABC       2020-02-02 10:00:00
2     ABC       2020-02-02 10:01:00
3     ABC       2020-02-02 10:02:00
4     ABC       2020-02-02 10:04:00
5     ABC       2020-02-02 10:07:00
```

The result I want is:
Now I want to get all dates where the job didn't get executed. So, at `10:03:00`, `10:05:00` and `10:06:00` the job didn't get executed!

Do you guys have any idea? I guess its a recursive query. This query needs to be written in postgres.

Comment: at a minimum we will need table structure, sample data and expected output

Comment: @GabrielDurac added, sorry for that. I thought its clear because its not much

Comment: And what if the third time is 10:02:01? of the times is 10:02:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Table_with_next AS (
  SELECT
   id
  ,job_name
  ,created_at 
  ,LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY created_at) as next_created_at
  FROM jobs 
)
SELECT
   job_name
  ,generate_series(created_at + interval '1 min'
                   ,next_created_at - interval '1 min'
                   ,interval '1 min') as time_not_run
FROM Table_with_next 
WHERE next_created_at-created_at > interval '1 min'
```

I used a CTE that contains the LEAD analytical function to get the next run timestamp. I then filtered the rows that have more than 1 minute between the runs and for those rows I generated 1 minute intervals between the run timestamp and the next run timestamp.

You can play around with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b237e/11

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want one job run per *calendar minute*.  That way, you are immune from 59 versus 61 second lags.

You don't need `lead()` for this.  Just generate the time series and join or use `not exists`:

```
select gs.job_name, gs.dt
from (select job_name,
             generate_series(min(date_trunc('minute', created_at)),
                             max(created_at), 
                             interval '1 minute'
                            ) as dt
      from tests
      group by job_name
     ) gs
where not exists (select 1
                  from tests t
                  where t.job_name = gs.job_name and
                        date_trunc('minute', t.created_at) = gs.dt
                 );
```